# Using php & javascript to make multiple dropdowns depend on each other

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created a webpage that needs to populate dropdowns from a MySQL database. Easy so far. I want to have multiple dropdowns depending on each other. In other words, I want the first drop down to change the values in the second, and so on. I tried this with sample code and it works fine. When I try it with my actual tables the second dropdown is not filtering based on the first. It is getting a value in the first dropdown (a course) and performing the prepared statement. But it is bringing back all the modules in the table, not just the ones for the selected courses.
I must have a typo in it as I have done it with sample tables and it works fine. Also, I have tried the SQL directly and it works also. Is my prepared statement OK? The 'connect_db.php' page is working fine with my sample tables also.
My code is

```
<?php
$page_title='My Dropdown Test';
include('header.html');
?>
<script>
function reload(form){
    var val=form.course.options[form.course.options.selectedIndex].value;

    self.location='CourseModuleDropDown.php?course=' + val ;
}
</script>
<?php
    require('../../connect_db.php');

if($dbc->connect_error) {
    die("Database connection failed");
}

$course=$_GET['course']; // Check that course is not empty
if(strlen($course) <= 0){ 
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
}
// ### Getting the data from Mysql table for course drop down ### //
$query2="SELECT DISTINCT name,CourseCode FROM courses order by name"; 

echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='next_page.php'>";

echo "<select name='course' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\">
        <option value=''>Select one</option>";

if($stmt = $dbc->query("$query2")){
    while ($row2 = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row2['CourseCode']==$course){
            echo "<option selected value='$row2[CourseCode]'>$row2[name]</option>";
        }else{
            echo  "<option value='$row2[CourseCode]'>$row2[name]</option>";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo $dbc->error;
}
echo "</select>";
// ###  End Course drop down list ### //

// ### Getting the data from Mysql table for module drop down (based on selected course)### //
echo "### $course ~ Length => ".strlen($course)." ###</br></br>"; // this was just for testing
echo "<select name='module'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
if(isset($course) and strlen($course) > 0){
    if($stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT ModuleCode FROM modules where CourseCode=? order by ModuleCode")){
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$course);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  "<option value='$row1[ModuleCode]'>$row1[ModuleCode]</option>";
        }
    }else{
        echo $dbc->error;
    }
}else{
    $query="SELECT DISTINCT ModuleCode FROM modules order by ModuleCode"; 

    if($stmt = $dbc->query("$query")){
        while ($row1 = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  "<option value='$row1[ModuleCode]'>$row1[ModuleCode]</option>";
        }
    }else{
        echo $dbc->error;
    }
}
echo "</select>";
// ###  End Module drop down list ### //

echo "<input type=submit value='Submit'></form>";
?>
<?php include('footer.html');?>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `$_GET['course']` has what you expect? Your line you marked as `// this was just for testing` ... what does it output?

Comment: Please add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script. You should see many warnings to resolve.

Comment: Why are you not using ajax to reload the dropdowns?

Comment: Thanks guys.
@IncredibleHat, I have confirmed that I am getting the correct value in my course variable.
Also, I have tried your suggestion and added in the display error settings. I am getting no errors